# More than one Navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios7

I'm new to iOS development. My Question is: Is it possible to combine two or more `UINavigationControllers`?

For example:

The app starts with an `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs. One tab should contain a `UITableView` with a detail view.

How can I implement such a navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact I've often used several navigation controllers.

The way to implement navigation within a tab is to have each tab start with a navigation controller. Like this...

```
                 |-(Tab)-[NavigationController]-[Content]-[Detail Content]
                 |
[Tab Controller]-|-(Tab)-[NavigationController]-[Content]
                 |
                 |-(Tab)-[NavigationController]-[Content]
```

And so on...

Each navigation controller then only deals with a single tab at a time. This provides the extra function of if you are on tab 1 and in the detail view and tap tab 1 again then it will pop all the way back to the root content view of that tab.